# Spring data sort a page by one property previously sorted by another

Tags: java, sorting, pagination, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a table employee (with id and name columns as follows):

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      adrian      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |       anne       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          9          |       bryce      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |       burns      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      charles     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       clyde      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to create a Page with, for example, size 3, and I need that the result page will be ordered first by `id` and then by `name`.

The point is, if I use the next query:

```
employeeRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("name").ascending().and(Sort.by("id").ascending()))
```

Is not re-ordering the page result by id just keeps the name order.

I've tried with, ordering first with spring data (OrderByName) and the by page request:

```
employeeRepository.findAllByOrderByName(PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("id").ascending()));
```

But I always get the next result:

Page 1

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      adrian      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |       anne       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          9          |       bryce      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Page 2

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |       burns      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      charles     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       clyde      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

But the result I need is:

Page 1

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |      anne        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          9          |       bryce      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      adrian      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Page 2

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      charles     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       clyde      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |       burns      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Notice that each page is re-ordered by id but keeping the first order by name.

Is there a way to do that just using Page and Sort or a post-process of the Page result is needed?

Any idea?